# Code Igniter MVC Displaying Basic View

Tags: php, codeigniter

Excuse me if this is slightly newbie.

I have the main view located @ app/views/index.php as:

```
<?php echo $head ?>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">
        <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

        <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
        <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

        <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
        <code>application/controllers/welcome.php</code>

        <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The header_meta.php file located at (app/views):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    <!--meta-->
```

the controller, named SpecialPage.php located at app/controllers/:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class SpecialPage extends CI_Controller {

    function SpecialPage(){
        parent::CI_Controller();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $head = $this->load->view('header_meta', '', true);
        $this->load->view('index', array('head' => $head));
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Error I'm getting on SpecialPage.php controller:
`Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller() on line 6`
which is:
`function SpecialPage(){
        parent::CI_Controller();
    }`

Why is this still just showing a 404 error?????

Comment: I forgot to ask: can we assume the installation worked using the CI's welcome page unmodified?

Comment: Yep, the default welcome worked fine. I basically renamed the welcome.php file (under app/view) to index.php and the controller for that from welcome_page.php to index.php (under app/controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's this line:

```
<?php $this->load->view('header_meta.php'); ?>
```

The ".php" extension seems to be the culprit.

BTW, I do not recommend using PHP code in your views (except echoes and loops). Much better is to compose it in your controller:

```
$head = $this->load->view('header_meta', '', true);
$this->load->view('index', array('head' => $head));
```

Obviously, the "$t>l>v()" must be changed to "echo $head". Or, the way I prefer (using a template view):

```
$body = $this->load->view('index', '', true);
$this->load->view('template', array('body' => $body));
```

Comment: your comment about NOT USING php in views... how do i get it to display on the /index.php file then and not use `<?php $this->load->view('header_meta'); ?>` . Please see updated code. This still is not working.

Comment: As I said, use an <?php echo $head ?> instead, with the second code block I wrote.

Comment: Oh, and I must add: the class must match the filename (i.e. "Index", not "SpecialPage").

Comment: How do I call this public function index() method in the view?

Comment: The view is called by the controller, not the opposite. If you access "myhost.com/index.php/index", CI will call the "index" method (by convention) of the "Index" controller.

Comment: Gotcha, so, what's up with this error I'm getting. See updated above.

Comment: Updated code still use a class named "SpecialPage". If you renamed the file to match this name, the URL should be "myhost.com/index.php/specialPage"

Comment: Please see the error above. I renamed it from SpecialPage to  specialPage ... same error

Comment: removed the  `function SpecialPage(){
  parent::CI_Controller();
 }`, seems to work. THanks for the awesome help!! I'm such a newbie, but this is the only way to learn! Thanks Eduardo!

Answer (score 1):

Your page should be named as:

- `specialPage.php` instead of index.php under your controller folder.
- Read [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) for more about controller naming conventions.
- This is either expected to use like `yourhost.com/index.php/specialPage` or `yourhost.com/specialPage` (if your `.htaccess` rewrite is enabled).
- Codeigniter tries to open a file depending upon what `classname` (via `controller/model`) you specify. Codenigniter has no idea why it should load `index.php` for your class files (unless you specify your classname as `Index`).

And I personally recommend not to use index.php for your files as it may confuse you and others, that this would be a self-loading file. Whereas, in codeigniter, the only self-loading file is `index.php` in the root folder of your codeigniter installation. And all other files are loaded through index.php (and files that it further includes) only.

Comment: simplePage.php ? where did you get simplePage ?

Comment: I am now getting  Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller()  on line 6 which is  `function SpecialPage(){
  parent::CI_Controller();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to your controller maybe you miss this

```
function SpecialPage(){

        parent::CI_Controller();
}
```

**Note :**
Make sure that your controller name is the same with the file name

And I have another question bro,How you call the page to load?

Gudluck!!

Comment: So controller name should be named SpecialPage.php then instead of index.php (located under app/controller) ?

Comment: Yes;please replace all the CI_Controller to Controller,maybe that's work

Answer (score 0):

The function `SpecialPage()` should be `__construct()` and `parent::CI_Controller()` should be `parent::__construct();.`


Good luck